# How to add people to Team without linking their Stack Overflow account

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, accounts

Recently I've been experimenting with creating Stack Overflow Teams for fun and interesting things like asynchronous book clubs.

However, I've found that people I invite often already have StackOverflow accounts, and that I can see the questions they have asked on their public profile. A substantial number of people have left the groups because they do not want their actual name and identity (which I know, because I know them in real life) to be associated with their "embarrassing" questions on StackOverflow.

**Is there any setting that can make it so that people's accounts on a Team page don't link to their public StackExchange profile, despite an account already existing with that email?**

(I've currently tagged this as a feature request in case this functionality doesn't exist, but if it does, it can be retagged as a discussion.)

Comment: As a workaround, they could create a second account and use that for Teams.  Of course, a workaround is suboptimal.

Comment: It's suboptimal enough that it's fully stopping me from using Teams right now. I want to use it for classes and group studying and book clubs and small projects, but asking people to create a new email and a new account just to join my stuff and protect their identity is too high of an ask. I really wish there was a way to (reasonably) disconnect the private and public profiles.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this was resolved with Stack Overflow for Teams moving to its own domain.

Comment: I agree - just checked a group where I'm an admin and the profiles no longer link back to regular Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow accounts. If you add this as an answer I will accept.